# Groupby Duplicated in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset of orderID and ProductID.

```
Order_ID, Item_ID
101,121
101,121
101,223
101,234
```

I want to check that which Item_ID came more than once in any particular Order.

output>

```
Order_ID, Item_ID, freq
101,121,2
```

Which will be the most efficient way to do this in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) or [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) first and then filter by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - faster in larger `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Order_ID','Item_ID']).size().reset_index(name='freq').query('freq > 1')
```

Alternative:

```
df1=df.groupby('Order_ID')['Item_ID'].value_counts().reset_index(name='freq').query('freq>1')
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Order_ID','Item_ID']).size().reset_index(name='freq')
df1 = df1[df1['freq'] > 1]
```

---

```
print (df1)
   Order_ID  Item_ID  freq
0       101      121     2
```